# Why doesn't MySQL use the primary key on JOIN plus ORDER?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, left-join

Here's a neat one for you (MySQL, obviously):

```
# Setting things up
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS index_test_gutza;
CREATE DATABASE index_test_gutza;
USE index_test_gutza;

CREATE TABLE customer_order (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
INSERT INTO customer_order
    (id, invoice)
    VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5);

CREATE TABLE customer_invoice (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_no MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    invoice_pdf LONGBLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
INSERT INTO customer_invoice
    (id, invoice_no)
    VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5);

# Ok, here's the beef
EXPLAIN
    SELECT co.id
    FROM customer_order AS co;

EXPLAIN
    SELECT co.id
    FROM customer_order AS co
    ORDER BY co.id;

EXPLAIN
    SELECT co.id, ci.invoice_no
    FROM customer_order AS co
    LEFT JOIN customer_invoice AS ci ON ci.id=co.invoice;

EXPLAIN
    SELECT co.id, ci.invoice_no
    FROM customer_order AS co
    LEFT JOIN customer_invoice AS ci ON ci.id=co.invoice
    ORDER BY co.id;
```

There are four EXPLAIN statements at the bottom. The first two result in exactly what you'd expect:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL |    5 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The third one is already interesting -- notice how the primary key in customer_order is not used any more:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                        |    5 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ci    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | index_test_gutza.co.invoice |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

The fourth one, however, is the zinger -- simply adding the ORDER BY *on the primary key* leads to filesort on customer_order (which is to be expected, given that it was already bewildered above):

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                        |    5 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ci    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | index_test_gutza.co.invoice |    1 | Using index    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------+
```

Filesort! And that while I'm never using anything except the primary key in the customer_order table for ordering, and the primary key in the customer_invoice table for the JOIN. So then, in the name of all that is good and right, **why does it switch to filesort all of a sudden?! And more importantly, how do I avoid this?** For the record, I will gladly accept a documented answer explaining why this **cannot** be avoided (if that's the case.)

As you probably suspect by now, this is actually happening in production, and although the tables are by no means huge (only hundreds of records), the filesort on the invoice table (which contains a PDF file) is killing the server when I run queries similar to the one above (which I need in order to know which orders have been issued invoices, and which weren't).

Before you ask, I designed the database, and I thought I was safe storing the PDF files in that table because I *never ever* need any search queries on it -- I always have its primary key at hand!

## Update (comments synopsis)

Here's a synopsis of what was suggested in the comments below, so you don't have to read all of that:

- *You should add a key on customer_order.invoice* -- I actually tried that in production, it makes no difference (as it shouldn't)
- *You should use `USE INDEX`* -- tried that, didn't work. I also tried `FORCE INDEX` -- no result either (no change whatsoever)
- *You oversimplified the use case, we need the actual production query* -- I might have stripped it a bit too much in the first iteration, so I updated it (I just added `, ci.invoice_no` in the `SELECT` for the last couple of queries). For the record, if anybody's really curious, here's the production query, exactly as it is (this retrieves the last page of orders):

```
SELECT
    corder.id,
    corder.public_id,
    CONCAT(buyer.fname," ",buyer.lname) AS buyer_name,
    corder.status,
    corder.payment,
    corder.reserved AS R,
    corder.tracking_id!="" as A,
    corder.payment_received as pay_date,
    invoice.invoice_no AS inv,
    invoice.receipt_no AS rec,
    invoice.public AS pub_inv,
    proforma.proforma_no AS prof,
    proforma.public AS pub_pf,
    corder.rating,
    corder.rating_comments!="" AS got_comment
FROM
    corder
LEFT JOIN user as buyer ON buyer.id=corder.buyer
LEFT JOIN invoice as invoice ON invoice.id=corder.invoice
LEFT JOIN invoice as proforma ON proforma.id=corder.proforma
ORDER BY
    id DESC 
LIMIT 400, 20;
```

The query above (which, again, is exactly what I run in production) takes about 14 seconds to run. Here's the simplified query, as shown in the use case above, executed on production:

```
SELECT
    corder.id,
    invoice.invoice_no
FROM
    corder
LEFT JOIN invoice ON invoice.id=corder.invoice
ORDER BY
    corder.id DESC 
LIMIT 400, 20;
```

This one takes 13 seconds to run. Be advised the LIMIT makes no difference whatsoever *as long as we're talking about the last page* of results (which we are). That is, there's absolutely no significant difference between retrieving the last 12 results or all 412 results when filesort is involved.

## Conclusion

ypercube's answer is not only correct, but unfortunately it seems to be the only legitimate one. I tried to further separate conditions from fields, because the `SELECT * FROM corder` subquery can end up involving a lot of data, if corder itself contains LONGBLOBs (and duplicating the fields from the main query in the subquery is inelegant), but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT
    corder.id,
    corder.public_id,
    CONCAT(buyer.fname," ",buyer.lname) AS buyer_name,
    corder.status,
    corder.payment,
    corder.reserved AS R,
    corder.tracking_id != "" AS A,
    corder.payment_received AS pay_date,
    invoice.invoice_no AS inv,
    invoice.receipt_no AS rec,
    invoice.public AS pub_inv,
    proforma.proforma_no AS prof,
    proforma.public AS pub_pf,
    corder.rating,
    corder.rating_comments!="" AS got_comment
FROM
    corder
LEFT JOIN user as buyer ON buyer.id = corder.buyer
LEFT JOIN invoice AS invoice ON invoice.id = corder.invoice
LEFT JOIN invoice AS proforma ON proforma.id = corder.proforma
WHERE corder.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM corder
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 400,20
)
ORDER BY
    corder.id DESC;
```

This fails, with the following error message:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I'm using MySQL 5.1.61, which is reasonably recent in the 5.1 family (and apparently this is not supported in 5.5.x either).

Comment: Do you not have an index on `customer_order (invoice)` that you use in the join? And I mean, in the production system. There is little value in testing with 5-rows tables. The execution plans may differ from the actual ones (with lots of rows).

Comment: I actually tried adding it when I was trying to understand this, but it doesn't make any difference (which was to be expected, if you think about it). Yes, I did that on production -- no difference.

Comment: Second, are the tables MyISAM or InnoDB? There is a difference.

Comment: And finally, your last (problematic) query is rather useless. You (LEFT) join to `customer_invoice` but you don't use it the SELECT. It would be better if you posted a useful query. Otherwise, why use the 4th that is only the second (but with possibly a lot of duplicate rows)?

Comment: MyISAM. You can add bells and whistles to that query if you like, it won't make any difference whatsoever (I obviously select more than just the order ID).

Comment: Do not let the word "filesort" deceive you. It has nothing to do with files. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: Please see the comments above for that. Ok, filesort (sometimes) has nothing to do with files; nevertheless this query is as slow as getting rich in this economy.

Comment: Well, when you add the suggested index, and provide a real query with the actual execution plan, someone may be interested. Sorry, but this is too localized.

Comment: If you have lots of rows (say 1000s) and lots of data in blobs (say 100KB per row), drop the `LONGBLOB` and similar fields, optimize the table and run the queries. You should notice a difference.

Comment: ypercube, I would gladly share the real query if that was really necessary, but I don't see how MORE crap would help -- I worked for a couple of hours to simplify it and reduce the use case to its essentials, precisely so you don't get bogged down in my implementation specifics.

Comment: Salman A, this is a classical case of the good, the bad and the ugly. My solution is obviously (and unexpectedly) bad. Your suggestion would work, but it's the ugly one. The real question is what's the good solution?

Comment: @Gutza: I understand you tried to simplify it and that is good. But it does matter if there are more columns (and their datatype) from one or the other table in the `SELECT` list. If the last query was changed to `SELECT co.*, ci.*`, would that be more close to what you have in production?

Comment: @ypercube: No, that's precisely the point, it does NOT matter - I have carefully stripped down my production query to its essentials. The actual EXECUTION TIME difference between the stripped down queries (as shown here) and the real queries (as actually used) are less than 10% when executed on production. E.g. if the actual query takes 11 seconds, the stripped down query as shown here takes 10 seconds.

Comment: @Gutza: ugly solution? give it a try. May be it will make your current database design ugly. I said about (re)moving the blobs from rows because I ran into same issue long time ago. I temporarily fixed it by _forcing_ an index, I eventually fixed it by moving blobs into another table.

Comment: @SalmanA, yes, it's obviously ugly -- a good, elegant solution keeps all related columns in a single table, isn't that obvious? Don't take this personal -- of course the ugliness can come directly from MySQL, in which case it's not your fault for suggesting the only viable option (aesthetics aside). But I'm still hoping there's some way to tell MySQL that it should use the primary keys when I sort by primary keys, you know? :)

Comment: Use the `USE INDEX` option to _force_ an index. And do some profiling too. It is not always the query that is slow, it could be the disk I/O.

Comment: @SalmanA, yes, `USE INDEX` is more like the kind of a solution I was thinking of. Unfortunately, it makes no difference. I even tried the relatively new `FORCE INDEX`, to no avail. Regarding profiling, the problem could be alleviated by improving the I/O throughput only if we assume we need filesort, and that filesort resorts to the filesystem (which it probably does in my case). But I'm trying to avoid filesort altogether, and if I manage that then I/O is a non-issue.

Comment: @ypercube: I experimented a bit with queries on production and you were right, I had oversimplified the use case a bit (if I don't select anything *at all* from the invoices table it does run a lot faster). I have edited the OP to reflect that, and I also included explicit examples in the final section.

Comment: What is the size of table that contains PDFs, in MBs?

Comment: @Gutza: You can't have `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT n)` in 5.5 either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this version (it basically gets first the 420 rows of the `corder` table, keeps the 20 of them and then does the 3 outer joins):

```
SELECT
    corder.id,
    corder.public_id,
    CONCAT(buyer.fname," ",buyer.lname) AS buyer_name,
    corder.status,
    corder.payment,
    corder.reserved AS R,
    corder.tracking_id != "" AS A,
    corder.payment_received AS pay_date,
    invoice.invoice_no AS inv,
    invoice.receipt_no AS rec,
    invoice.public AS pub_inv,
    proforma.proforma_no AS prof,
    proforma.public AS pub_pf,
    corder.rating,
    corder.rating_comments!="" AS got_comment
FROM
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM corder
      ORDER BY
        id DESC 
      LIMIT 400, 20
    )
    AS corder
LEFT JOIN user as buyer ON buyer.id = corder.buyer
LEFT JOIN invoice AS invoice ON invoice.id = corder.invoice
LEFT JOIN invoice AS proforma ON proforma.id = corder.proforma
ORDER BY
    corder.id DESC ;
```

Comment: 0.09 seconds, compared to 12-14 seconds before. **This** is the good solution I was talking about before. Tip of the hat to you, sir! I'm sad that there appears to be no way of coercing MySQL to do this by itself, but I guess this is as good as it gets.